# Liferay 6.2 languages switching

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

In my portal all authenticated users have as default language English. In pages' theme there is a language selector using $taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "languageId", 3) which gets all languages that I have selected inside portal-ext.properties(locales=en_GB,fr_FR,de_DE).
All these languages are displayed normally in selector, but when a logged-in user tries to switch a language in selector, the selected option remains always the user's language. e.g. A user with English language cannot switch to French. Although, the language changes in selector, the page is reloaded in English with selector's option turned to English.

Does anyone has a workaround on this?

Note: The mappings in web.xml are correct.

Comment: There was some change in 6.2 regarding language parameters... will try to find details.

Comment: Have you verified that the user has appropriate permissions in language portlet in order to perform the change in language? See also https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-30356, which could be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "_82_languageId", 3)
```

or

```
$theme.language("fm", null, "_82_languageId", 3)
```